# Посоветуйте контейнер Java

Tags: stl, очередь, java

Делаю операцию ctrl-z / ctrl-y.

Для сохранения состояния хочу использовать контейнер.
Нужна некая очередь с ограниченным размером - до 10 заполняется нормально, после 10 выталкивается первый.
Также особенность - нужно доступ по элементу, чтобы знать в каком состоянии нахожусь, а также мочь быстро удалять все, что после указанного состояния.

Полез в Deque - нет доступа по элементу.

Понятно, что можно сделать ArrayList: remove first; for size сдвиг - не очень красивое решение. Понятно, что можно написать свой контейнер, не хочется особо засиживаться на этой задаче, итак полно работы.

Короче, плохо знаю местные контейнеры, посоветуйте что-нибудь.

Comment: не называй коллекции контейнером, не путай людей

Comment: Мне кажется, вам подойдет [`CircularFifoQueue`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html) из `Apache Common Collections.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) как стэк. Методы `push` и `pop` для организации LIFO-очереди, `removeLast` для удаления самого старого элемента при превышении емкости очереди, `indexOf/lastIndexOf` для получения индекса по объекту и `get` для получения объекта по индексу.

Размер придется контролировать самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо